# How to store chunk of html markup into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to extract a user `input` html data and store them in an `object` or `array`

The source of `html` could be as following

```
begin <em>texts</em>
    description texts here

<table>
   <tr><td>cell 1<td><td>cell2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>cell 3<td><td>cel4</td></tr>
</table>

<em>second<em> part texts

<table>
   <tr><td>cell 5<td><td>cell6</td></tr>
   <tr><td>cell 7<td><td>cel8</td></tr>
</table>
```

I need to be able to store the following things.

all the texts outside of table and the cell data in table.
they need to be in order.

I have tried

```
var data = [];
sourceHtml.contents().each(function(){
    if($(this).is('table')){
          var table = $(this)
          var rows = 'rows:' + $('tr', table).length;
          var column ='column:' + $('td', table).length / $('tr', table).length;
          //i need to get the table columns and rows counts
          data.push(rows)
          data.push(column)

          table.find('td').each(function(){
              data.push($(this).text().trim());
          })
        }else{
          data.push($(this).text().trim());
        }
 })
```

The above will only give me all the texts in the `sourceHtml` but lose all the `markup` for my texts. Are there anyway to maintain the `html` markup while getting texts of my data? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: do you have only 1 table?

Comment: Instead of using `.text()` use `.html()`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$(this).text().trim()` use `$(this).html()`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()` to get an element's HTML markup content instead of text node content.

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: thanks, but for some reasons, all the texts return null when I change  }else{
          data.push($(this).html().trim());
        } +1